# Element img not allowed as child of element picture in this context

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

My Example

```
<figure>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="/images/main/main_visual_01_md.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/main/main_visual_01_md.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/main/main_visual_01.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="/images/main/main_visual_01.jpg">
    <img src="/images/main/main_visual_01_md.jpg" class="visible-md visible-lg" alt="샐러드 접시">
    <img src="/images/main/main_visual_01.jpg" class="visible-xs visible-sm" alt="샐러드 접시">
  </picture>
  <figcaption class="blind">치즈와 키토제닉 전용 빵이 들어간 샐러드 접시</figcaption>
</figure>
```

html5 validator said "Element img not allowed as child of element picture in this context."

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The picture element can contain only one IMG element.  The error is due to the extraneous child.

Here's a bit more information on the Picture element:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture